# How to make div size bigger?

Tags: css, html

Here is the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/wA6s1jgE1QuacGxhOeoP?p=preview

I have tried to make size of

```
    <div class="pure-u-1 header">
        <div class="header-buttons">
            <button class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Add</button>
            <a class="pure-button pure-button-primary">settings</a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

**bigger** but not able to

**Questions**

1. How can I make `.header` bigger?
2. How can I align `.header-buttons` on the right?

I am sure CSS will have a way, but I don't know how, please guide to relevant sources to learn.

Thank you

Comment: By using the `height` and `width` properties.

Comment: This could have been answered with a simple Google search.

Comment: You can use `padding`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

```css
#main .header {
    padding: 1em;
    height: 5%;
    background-color: #15e6c5;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#main .header .pull-right {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

And HTML

```
        <div class="header-buttons">
            <button class="pure-button pure-button-primary pull-right">Add</button>
            <a class="pure-button pure-button-primary pull-right">settings</a>
        </div>
```

#### Fiddle: http://plnkr.co/edit/rdhZKIB4xYBqqsENpl0Z?p=preview

Comment: @daydreamer: note the use here of 'padding: ...' not 'padding-top: ...'

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I need to learn more of CSS actually

Answer (score 1):

You must use an exact value such as 4em or 50px.  5% seems to be acting as a minimum value in this case where the contents are taller than 5% of the window.  So the actual height is based on the contents and not the window.

You can also use lower padding to make it pretty and balanced.

Comment: Thank you, this is an wise advice